Help with Integration by Parts for a Markov Chain
I am trying to follow the equations on page 14/page 15 in these notes https://people.unipmn.it/bobbio/DIDATTICA/MODQ/ctmcfig.pdf , but avoid using Laplace Transforms and instead use first principles from Probability.
Specifically, I am trying to find out the variance for the "expected time to absorption" of a Continuous Time Markov Chain (CTMC).
Suppose I have the following partitioned matrix (representing the generator matrix of a CTMC, fundamental matrix form, https://lips.cs.princeton.edu/the-fundamental-matrix-of-a-finite-markov-chain/):
$$
Q = \begin{bmatrix}
B & A=-BI \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I was able to derive the probability distribution function for the time to absorption ($P_0$ is the initial probability vector):
$$f(t) = - P_0 \cdot B \cdot Exp(Bt)$$
From first principles, I know that:
$$E(t) = \int f(t) \cdot t \ dt$$
I can apply this above concept to my problem:
$$E(t) = \int_{\infty}^{0} - P_0 B Exp(Bt) t \ dt = \int_{0}^{\infty} P_0 B Exp(Bt) t \ dt = P_0 B \int_{0}^{\infty} Exp(Bt) t \ dt$$
Now, to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} Exp(Bt) t \ dt$, I can use integration by parts $\int u \ dv = uv - \int v \ du$.
I can define:
$$u=t$$
$$Exp(Bt)dt=dv$$
Now, I can further define:
$$u = t \Rightarrow du = dt$$
$$v = \int dv = \int Exp(Bt) \ dt = \frac{Exp(Bt)}{B}$$
I also evaluated the following integral:
$$\int \frac{Exp(Bt)}{B} \ dt = \frac{1}{B} \frac{Exp(Bt)}{B} = \frac{1}{B^2}Exp(Bt) $$
Here is where I get stuck:
$$\int u \ dv = uv - \int v \ du$$
$$\int u \ dv = \frac{t Exp(Bt)}{B} - \int \frac{Exp(Bt)}{B} \ dt = \frac{t Exp(Bt)}{B} - \frac{1}{B^2} Exp(Bt)$$
Now to evaluate this expression at the correct limits:
$$\left[ \frac{t Exp(Bt)}{B} - \frac{1}{B^2} Exp(Bt) \right]_{\infty}^{0} = - \frac{1}{B^2}  - \infty + \infty $$
And this is not correct.
On page 15 (https://people.unipmn.it/bobbio/DIDATTICA/MODQ/ctmcfig.pdf), the correct answer is given by (note that here, $e$ is an elementary vector):
$$E(t) = \int_{\infty}^{0} - P_0 B e^{Bt} t \ dt =  P_0 (-B)^{-1} e^T$$
Can someone please help me correct my work?
Thanks!

OP here, I think I was able to figure out the problem.
Part 1: Let's start with the Q Matrix:
$$
Q = \begin{bmatrix}
B & A=-BI \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Within this matrix, we are interested in the sub-matrix $B$ required for the desired integral:
$$E(t) = \int_{\infty}^{0} - P_0 B Exp(Bt) t \ dt = \int_{0}^{\infty} P_0 B Exp(Bt) t \ dt = P_0 B \int_{0}^{\infty} Exp(Bt) t \ dt$$
The desired integral being:
$$  \int_{0}^{\infty} Exp(Bt) t \ dt$$
Part 2: Since the $B$ matrix is a partition from the $Q$ matrix (the $Q$ matrix is the generator matrix of a CTMC), we can infer the following properties of $B$.

All diagonals elements within $B$ are negative
In each row of $B$, the absolute value of each diagonal element is greater than the sum of all other element in that row

As an example, $B$ might look like this:
$$
B = \begin{bmatrix}
-x_{11} & x_{12} & \cdots & x_{1j} \\
x_{21} & -x_{22} & \cdots & x_{2j} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
x_{i1} & x_{i2} & \cdots & -x_{ij}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Such that:

$|x_{11}| >  |x_{12} + x_{13} + \cdots + x_{1j}|$
$|x_{22}| >  |x_{21} + x_{23} + \cdots + x_{2j}|$
$\vdots$
$|x_{ii}| >  |x_{i1} + x_{i2} + \cdots + x_{i(j-1)}|$

Part 3: Now, using the Gershgorin Circle Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) will be used to infer properties of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the submatrix $B$.
The Gershgorin Circle Theorem states that each row of a matrix corresponds to a geometric "disc". This disc has a center located at the diagonal element and a radius equal to the absolute (value of the) sum of all other elements in that row (i.e. excluding the diagonal element). The Gershgorin Circle Theorem also states that the eigenvalues of a matrix are located within the subset of all discs corresponding to this matrix.
In the case of the submatrix $B$, we know that all diagonal elements are negative (this is always the case in the generator matrix $Q$ of a CTMC). In the full $Q$ matrix, in any row, the negative of the diagonal element is equal to the sum of all other elements in that row. Since the submatrix $B$ is a left-partition of the full $Q$ matrix, we know that in any row of $B$, the absolute value of the diagonal element will be greater than the sum of all other elements. Furthermore, the center of all discs corresponding to the submatrix $B$ will be on the negative side.
Putting all this logic together, this means that for the submatrix $B$, the radius of any given disc will be smaller than the distance between the center of the disc and the origin of the Cartesian Plane. This means that all eigenvalues for $B$ will be negative.
Part 4: Now, we will use another classic result in linear algebra about matrix diagonalization. If $A$ is a square matrix, we can diagonalize $A$ in terms of its eigenvalues and eigenvectors:
$$ A = PDP^{-1} $$
Such that:
$$ \text{det}(A - λI) = 0 $$
$$ (A - λI)v = 0 $$
$$ P = [v_1, v_2, ..., v_n] $$
$$ D = \begin{bmatrix} λ_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & λ_2 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & λ_n \end{bmatrix} $$
And in general, we know that a series expansion for a matrix $A$ looks like this:
$$\exp(A) = I + A + \frac{A^2}{2!} + \frac{A^3}{3!} + \frac{A^4}{4!} + \cdots$$
In this series expansion, we replace every occurrence of $A$ with $PDP^{-1}$:
$$\exp(A) = I + PDP^{-1} + \frac{(PDP^{-1})^2}{2!} + \frac{(PDP^{-1})^3}{3!} + \frac{(PDP^{-1})^4}{4!} + \cdots$$
Note the following pattern:
$$(PDP^{-1})^2 = (PDP^{-1})(PDP^{-1}) = PDIDP^{-1} = PD^2P^{-1} $$
$$(PDP^{-1})^3 = (PDP^{-1})(PDP^{-1})(PDP^{-1}) =  PD^3P^{-1} $$
$$etc.$$
Going back to the series expansion, if we sub in this pattern:
$$\exp(A) = I + PDP^{-1} + \frac{PD^2P^{-1}}{2!} + \frac{PD^3P^{-1}}{3!} + \frac{PD^4P^{-1}}{4!} + \cdots$$
Now if we multiply by $P$ and $P^{-1}$, we can write:
$$ \exp(A) =  P \left[ I + D + \frac{D^2}{2!} + \frac{D^3}{3!} + \ldots \right] P^{-1} $$
We can see that the inside term between $P$ and $P^{-1}$ is also a matrix series expansion:
$$Exp(D) = \left[ I + D + \frac{D^2}{2!} + \frac{D^3}{3!} + \ldots \right]$$
Thus, it becomes:
$$ \exp(A) =  P Exp(D) P^{-1} $$
Since $D$ is a Diagonal Matrix of eigenvalues, its exponent becomes:
$$ Exp(D) = \begin{bmatrix} exp(λ_1) & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & exp(λ_2) & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & exp(λ_n) \end{bmatrix} $$
Thus, we can see that if some matrix $A$ has eigenvalues $\lambda$, then $Exp(A)$ has eigenvalues $Exp(\lambda)$
Part 5: Revisiting the desired integral
$$  \int_{0}^{\infty} Exp(Bt) t \ dt$$
Using integration by parts, we got:
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} Exp(Bt) t \ dt = \frac{t Exp(Bt)}{B} - \frac{1}{B^2} Exp(Bt)$$
Now, to evaluate this integral at its limits:
$$\left[ \frac{t Exp(Bt)}{B} - \frac{1}{B^2} Exp(Bt) \right]_{0}^{\infty} = 0  - 0 - 0  +  \frac{1}{B^2} =  \frac{1}{B^2}$$
Part 6: But why does this happen? This is because the submatrix $B$ can be written as:
$$ \exp(B) =  P Exp(D) P^{-1} $$
We had shown earlier that in the case of the submatrix $B$, all eigenvalues are negative. Therefore in this case, $D$ will look like:
$$ D = \begin{bmatrix} -λ_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & -λ_2 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & -λ_n \end{bmatrix} $$
And the Exponent of $D$ will look like:
$$ Exp(D) = \begin{bmatrix} Exp(-λ_1) & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & Exp(-λ_2) & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & Exp(-λ_n) \end{bmatrix} $$
More specific to the desired integral, we can write:
$$ \exp(Bt) =  P Exp(Dt) P^{-1} $$
$$ Exp(Dt) = \begin{bmatrix} Exp(-λ_1 t) & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & Exp(-λ_2 t) & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & Exp(-λ_n t) \end{bmatrix} $$
From here, we can clearly see that:
$$\lim_{{t \to \infty}} Exp({-\lambda t}) = 0$$
And this is exactly what is taking place within the integral, e.g.:
$$\left. \frac{1}{B^2} e^{Bt} \right|_0^\infty = \lim_{{t \to \infty}} \left(\frac{1}{B^2} e^{Bt}\right) - \lim_{{t \to 0}} \left(\frac{1}{B^2} e^{Bt}\right)$$
This gives us the correct answer as in math notes (i.e. page 14/page15 within https://people.unipmn.it/bobbio/DIDATTICA/MODQ/ctmcfig.pdf) and we can use this to derive the distribution of the absorption times for a Continuous Time Markov Chain (CTMC).
