When are all Eigenvalues of a Matrix negative?
Suppose I have the following matrix where:

All diagonals are negative
In each row, the absolute value of each diagonal element is greater than the sum of all other element in that row

Suppose this matrix looks like this:
$$
X = \begin{bmatrix}
-x_{11} & x_{12} & \cdots & x_{1j} \\
x_{21} & -x_{22} & \cdots & x_{2j} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
x_{i1} & x_{i2} & \cdots & -x_{ij}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Such that:

$|x_{11}| >  |x_{12} + x_{13} + \cdots + x_{1j}|$
$|x_{22}| >  |x_{21} + x_{23} + \cdots + x_{2j}|$
$\vdots$
$|x_{ii}| >  |x_{i1} + x_{i2} + \cdots + x_{i(j-1)}|$

My Question: In this kind of matrix, is it possible to mathematically prove that all eigenvalues of this matrix will always be negative?
Thanks!

Note: I am currently working on this question here Help with Integration by Parts for a Markov Chain ... if this eigenvalue property holds true, I think I might be able to solve my first question (I am working on posting an answer for that question)


OP here: Can this be proven using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem ?

cleaned up counter example: $\left[\begin{matrix}-1 & 2 & -2\-2 & -1 & 2\-2 & 2 & -1\end{matrix}\right]$ which has eigenvalues of $+1, -1, -3$.  Notice that each row of off-diagonals sums to zero.

Thank you for your reply

I need this result for this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4895711/help-with-integration-by-parts-for-a-markov-chain ... any ideas?
